# Tool for monitoring of breaking changes?

Tags: node.js, bower, dependency-management

Do you know any tool that monitors breaking changes in github npm or bower projects?

I'd like to list all changes from commit history that are marked with breaking change and list them.

I am using npm-check-updates, that tells me what is new, but it doesn't tell me what has been changed since.

Recently, I have found greenkeeper.io, but as far as I know it doesn't list what is new, it just simply does upgrade and see if your tests are still running. If tests fails, you have to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In ideal opensource world author marks every breaking change. Also he writes code without bugs. In the real world is not true. You have opensource packages for free, but with possible bugs and undocumented changes API.

There is only working answer, testing your application for each dependencies update. You should have tests and shrinkwrap file.

greenkeeper.io is amazing tool. It makes pull request with dependency changelog. Check [example](https://github.com/cybertk/abao/pull/196)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I guess this is not a science fiction, if a library use the semantic release and follow some git message format, e.g. angular or any other standard one, you can already get something by using a changelog generators. The only thing is that there are lot of pieces of work done, but not merged together in the one tool. I hought that there must be a solution that puts all these pieces together, perhaps this is a invitation for making it :)